# Security events taxonomy

Tags: security, taxonomy, auditing

We are currently implementing a security log monitoring/auditing application for local law compliance.
In our first implementation we used the security event taxonomy proposed by the [OpenGroup XDAS](https://www.opengroup.org/projects/security/xdas/) working group since the interesting Common Event Expression (http://cee.mitre.org) effort is apparently going nowhere.
Are there any other similar open projects/standards we can look at?

Answer (score 0):

The [OSVDB](http://osvdb.org/api/about) is along these same lines.  OSVDB a database of vulnerabilities that traces back to CVE numbers as well as Snort and Nessus IDs

[Snort](http://www.snort.org) is a very nice IDS and I highly recommend looking at their database of rules.  All of their rule sets trace back to CVE numbers or in some cases to other resources when a CVE number isn't applicable.